# Updating UITableView with new data

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview, xcode4.2

I have a table view, with a data.

I'm getting data from a server, so how can I reload the table view with the number of cells, data, and etc'?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you get your data, you should just call

```
[tableView reloadData]
```